# Wordpress: Fetch custom field value in the right language (WPML)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field (using ACF Plugin) called "my_custom_field". Then I use this code to get the value for that custom field **which works fine**:

```
echo $output = get_post_meta($data['post_id'], "my_custom_field", true);
```

My site have two languages (french and spanish). I use WPML for translations.

**Problem** is that the $output always shows the value for the default language (french) even if the $output is loaded and printed in an "spanish" page.

I guess that I need to add something else in my code to detect the language and show the $output accordingly.

Comment: Hi, have you tried using the [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function of ACF?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this fixed the problem:

```
$wpml_post_id = icl_object_id($data['post_id'], 'page', false,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
echo $output = get_post_meta($wpml_post_id, "my_custom_field", true);
```

Comment: Better to use ACFML and use the `get_field` function. Less code less problem

Answer (score 1):

To make the ACF field translatable for WPML you need to install the ACFML plugin that you can download from your account on the WPML website.

With this plugin, you can make ACF fields translatable. More you can read inside official documentation: https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/translate-sites-built-with-acf/